# Maven Java compiler - compilation error using wrong compliance version

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

When Running install from Eclipse we have no issues as the compiler version is set to 1.8.

When running mvn install in terminal we get the following error.

```
 ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project servicehelper: Compilation failure
    [ERROR]   try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
    [ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
    [ERROR]
```

When using mvn install -X we're seeing -target 1.5

However here are my java and javac versions

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T14:39:06-05:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131
```

I seems like from every version i run that we should have 1.8 compliance but maven target continues to try and install with 1.5 compliance.

Comment: Maven defaults source/target compliance to 1.5 (don't ask, I don't know why), you will have to update the POM to support your target - See [Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add this plugin to your pom.xml file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Only works if fork is set. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerVersion

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is first to define the version of the used plugin which means:

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

You should always pin plugin versions which means all used plugin in your build.

The other option to define the [java version (source/target)](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) can be done via:

```xml
<project>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Or you can omit the pluginManagement if you have already pinned the plugin version via a corporate pom parent and only give the above properties.

If you have to run Maven with another JDK than you need to compile/test your code you need to go via [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)

Or you can define the compiler to use via [fork option](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) which means to hard code the location of your JDK in your pom file which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the tag `java.version` on your pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: This property is not picked up from any plugin I know ?